# How to make the JInternalFrame of the specified size?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

I have a `JFrame`. 
I have added menu-bar to it.
I have set its size and location using following line.

```
frmMain.setBounds(0, 0, 1024, 768);  // JFrame
```

Next I have added a `JInternalFrame` to the code for `JInternalFrame` as follows:

```
ifActivateProject=new JInternalFrame();
ifActivateProject.setBounds(450, 400, 300, 350);
ifActivateProject.add(pnlActivateProject);
ifActivteProject.setVisible(true);
ifActivateProject.setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frmMain.getContentPane().add(ifActivateProject);
```

When I executes the program the Internal frame occupies all the remaining area in `JFrame`. As I have set the location and size of internal frame. It wont appear at that location and of the specified size.

I want to show Internal frame of different sizes depending on menu click means on one menu click one internal frame has shown.  After closing that internal frame on another menu click another should be appear in my `JFrame`. All these internal frames are of different sizes. But the problem is the added internal frame as shown in above code snippet acquires all the space of `JFrame`.

What's wrong with above code?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `JInternalFrrame` should be added to a [`JDesktopPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html), not a `JFrame`.

See [How to Use Internal Frames](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes. I forgot about JDesktopPane and answered for running `setBounds(...)`. :/